# Connection refused on KOPS deployed master node in kubernetes cluster hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I'm doing a little R&D on Kubernetes and deploying clusters on AWS. I'm using KOPS to do the heavy lifting and provisioning the cluster with Terraform.

My goal is testing the behavior of Kubernetes when a port that is essential to a particular service has been blocked on a node hosting pods provide the service. To do so, I wanted to ssh into my master node and manually block the port on a worker.

I've been running the following command :

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa admin@<master_ip>
```

only to have the following response

```
ssh: connect to host <master_ip> port 22: Connection refused
```

This is the command that I've been using to create my cluster :

```
kops create cluster \
--name=${KOPS_NAME} \
--state=${KOPS_STATE_STORE} \
--zones=eu-central-1a,eu-central-1b,eu-central-1c \
--master-zones=eu-central-1a,eu-central-1b,eu-central-1c  \
--node-count=5 \
--node-size=t2.micro \
--master-size=t2.micro \ 
--ssh-public-key=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub \
--out=. \
--target=terraform
```

The security groups on AWS, in which my masters are enrolled, allow traffic on the port 22 and running a

```
kops describe secret admin
```

shows that there is a public key attributed to the admin user.

I do not think this is a bug, as there is no one else that seems to have this problem on the KOPS git, and, while I am far from an expert in AWS, it would seem odd to me that this is a problem with AWS.

**EDIT**

```
$> ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa <adress>.elb.amazon.com -vvv
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "<address>.elb.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <address>.elb.amazonaws.com [ip address] port 22.
```

Comment: Some questions: Are you sure that all your instances with masters have `Ready` state? Is your `<master_ip>` is public IPv4 address? Are you sure that Security Groups of your masters allow to connect to the port 22 from your IP?

Comment: 1. Yes. I wait about 10 minutes for the cluster is completely initialized and every node (worker and master) is ready
2. I've tried the ssh with the public and private IPv4 addresses
3. I've checked the incoming traffic rules in my master security group and the port 22 is open

Comment: Can you try to ssh with `-vvvv`, just to get more details? It still looks as a network of a firewall issue.

Comment: Hey @AntonKostenko , I updated my response. I've had to work on other issues these last couple of weeks so I've hadn't had to time to come back to this one

Answer (score 0):

Use can use a `--bastion` flag while provisioning cluster. Then use the bastion host to ssh into master. This approach has been working for us.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has not resolved the image for me. Any ssh attempt hangs. I imagine that just to do with the setup of AWS in my company, and I do not have my hands on that part :/

Comment: @JuEast Maybe internet gateway your company is using is blocking the port for any SSH attempt(Happened in our case). Try form home or personal hotspot. If thats not the case please check the Security Group rules for the bastion host. You must hit the bastion ELB which should redirect you to bastion box.